# npm - Error: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: node.js, npm

**Error:**

```
module.js:347
        ' for module ' + JSON.stringify(this.id));
                       ^
Error: The specified procedure could not be found.
c:\Users\Artur\workspace\xxx\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64\binding.node
    at Error (native)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Artur\workspace\xxx\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:211:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
```

**System:**

- **OS**: Windows 8.1 (64-bit)
- **node**: v0.12.0
- **npm**: 2.5.1

**Background:**

Yesterday I was trying to start a new project. And tried to use yeoman generator `generator-gulp-angular` and got a bunch of visual basic errors. So I installed `Microsoft Windows SDK` and a bunch of other stuff from Microsoft. So now I have a lot of Microsoft entries in my installed applications listing and I'm lost when I look at these:

```
These might be relevant for the problem:

Microsoft Visual C++  x64 Libraries
Microsoft Visual C++  x86 Libraries
Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable
Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable
Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable
Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable (x64)
Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable (x64)
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x64 9.0.30729.4148
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x64 9.0.30729.6161
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 9.0.30729.4148
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 9.0.30729.4974
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010  x64 Redistributable - 10.0.40219
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express - ENU
Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 x64 Additional Runtime - 11.0.61030
Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 x64 Minimum Runtime - 11.0.61030
Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 x86 Additional Runtime - 11.0.61030
Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 x86 Minimum Runtime - 11.0.61030
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 32bit Compilers - ENU Resources
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Core Libraries
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 x64 Additional Runtime - 12.0.21005
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 x64 Debug Runtime - 12.0.21005
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 x64 Minimum Runtime - 12.0.21005
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 x86 Additional Runtime - 12.0.21005
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 x86 Debug Runtime - 12.0.21005
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 x86 Minimum Runtime - 12.0.21005
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 x86-x64 Compilers

Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 SDK (x64) - ENU
Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 Multi-Targeting Pack
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 SDK
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 Multi-Targeting Pack
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 Multi-Targeting Pack (ENU)
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 SDK
```

**I have no idea what I really need/don't need or if anything is conflicting.**

I didn't get anything to work yesterday so I finished right there.

So today I found out that I had an old version of npm (1.4.28) and upgraded it to version 2.5.1. I just downloaded a new x64 installer from [nodejs.org](http://nodejs.org).

After that everything was broken. I can't even run `gulp serve` anymore to launch my existing/working application. For hours I tried to download/repair/uninstall/install `Windows SDK`, `nodejs` etc. Tried a bunch of commands which I still don't fully understand and I'm still lost.

Few things from the top of my head which I tried:

- `npm cache clean`
- deleted node_modules folder and ran npm install
- tried some commands I found with `node-gyp`
- tried to set the `msvs_version` attribute to *something*
- restart

The error makes me think that something is wrong with some kind of a compiler.
But I have no idea what's really going on. So I'm trying to understand what could be the cause of the problem? What should I try next to fix the error?

If any addition information is needed let me know.

Comment: Did you try removing node_modules and re-installing it (maybe only `npm install` will do the trick)? It happened to me that plugins would break upon update. Btw, when updating, use `npm -g update npm` (or replace `update` with `install`, I think it should work the same). Form my experience, using this did not break anything upon updating.

Comment: So I tried that. Also tried now to remove nodejs, delete node_modules, reinstall nodejs, `npm install` - still no dice.

After that I tried to uninstall nodejs, delete node_modules. Installed nodejs x86 and ran `npm install`. But still when I try to use gulp or anything at all I get the same error.

Also I uninstalled `Microsoft Visual C++ 2010` - because I read something about using 2010 and 2012 side by side. After that I didn't need to specify the `--msvs_version=2013` when doing `npm install`.

Comment: Just finished uninstalling all of the "Microsoft Corporation" stuff from my Control Panel. Also removed nodejs and python 3.4. Removed all global node_modules and cleaned cache. After that installed nodejs, Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop and I'm still running into the same problem with my app. Interesting thing is that I now got the gulp-angular-generator to work. And that started up flawlessly. Soon will try to pull my project to a new folder and see where I can go from there. Maybe there is some hidden "cache" or some temp files that are still getting in the way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**EDIT (APRIL 2ND, 2015):**

Node-sass has since fixed the issue. You can safely use Node v0.12, just make sure to install the latest version of Node-sass and also update your local AND global version of Gulp (https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/873). I'll leave the original response below for archiving purposes.

---

Uninstall Node v0.12 and install Node v0.10.28

http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.28/

You'll want the .msi installer

That fixed the issue for me.

Apparently it's an issue with node-sass that won't be fixed until they update:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/653

Comment: @RobertRossmann Well the only alternative is to wait for node-sass to upgrade to v2.0.

If you need to _fix_ your workflow NOW, then you'll have to downgrade.

Comment: Nice! I just finished comparing a working project with a broken one and managed to narrow the problem down to `gulp-sass` (`node-sass`). I was in the process of checking out `gulp-ruby-sass` to see if maybe that helps until I saw your edit! Thanks for cracking the case!

Comment: @MisterOh You are my super hero :)