# Cannot Deploy Marklogic 8 - SampleStack

Tags: installation, sample, marklogic

I am new to Marklogic 8 , and I was hoping some experts here can help me out. Essentially, I have installed ML8 and had successfully run through some of the exercises that were suggested. I would like to test SampleStack, so I proceeded with the instructions [here](https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-samplestack#getting-started).

I'm not able to install the browser application, with the information presented here, specifically the [section](https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-samplestack/blob/master/browser/README.md) to "Set up the Angular.js/Gulp development environment" ().

here is my current challenge:

1. `gulp run` returns this error:

   ```
   [00:19:40] Starting 'clean'...
   [00:19:40] Finished 'clean' after 8.34 ms
   [00:19:40] Starting 'bower-files'...
   [00:19:40] Finished 'bower-files' after 39 ms
   [00:19:40] Starting 'build'...
   [00:19:41] 'build' errored after 453 ms
   [00:19:41] Error: The specified procedure could not be found.
   G:\app\marklogic\marklogic-samplestack-master\browser\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64\binding.node
    at Error (native)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (G:\app\marklogic\marklogic-samplestack-master\browser\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:211:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
   ```

   [00:19:41] processing files
   [00:19:42] saw 217 files

A quick check of gulp tells me both have been set to 3.8.11

```
G:\app\marklogic\marklogic-samplestack-master\browser>gulp -v
[00:23:52] CLI version 3.8.11
[00:23:52] Local version 3.8.11
```

any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've run into an issue with [node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/653) on node v0.12, which is expected to be fixed in [node-sass v2.0.0](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/602).

As discussed in that thread, you can manually compile and link node-sass to fix the issue. Or, as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28440743/920052), you can downgrade node to [v0.10](http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.28/).

Comment: I took a look at my node installation, and it appears I have 2.1.1 of node-sass. am i looking at something else?

Comment: Take a look at your node version: `node -v`

Comment: Interestingly, the link provided (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28435005/npm-error-the-specified-procedure-could-not-be-found/28440743#28440743) mentions an updated node 0.12 which resolves this. Would I still need to downgrade?